# Spring Security ACL tags for REST Services

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, acl

I am new to Posting question in Stack Overflow.

I am currently implementing Spring Security ACL for my REST Services.

What i want is a way to hide and show certain UI tags based on ACL entry.

Since i am using REST Services - All my calls from UI  are ajax based and returns a JSON.

Now with Spring Security ACL tags its required to send a DomainObject to the tag so that it can resolve the authorization.

Since i get a JSON from backend i cant create a DomainObject.

Also the time i return a JSON to frontened the JSP will be delivered in first place so the security tag will not be effected.

Best Regards
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by returning a json which will have crud variables marked true or false depending on the users access control and in the ui I show/hide using this data.